# jquery json request failed

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a json call with jquery but noting happened. My code:

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#TwImport").click(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://<?php echo $_conf['siteurl']; ?>/files/connect/import/customers.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert(data.percentage); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$output = array(
    'percentage' => "50"
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "nothing happened".  Really? Any javascript errors? Do you run with firebug on, or some other javascript console that will show you if there's an error?

Comment: Any errors? Are you POSTing to a different domain, which isn't allowed using AJAX?

Comment: does the ajax call execute the code in `success` callback ? (Put an alert to verify)

Comment: If the site making the request is not using the `https://` protocol you could be falling foul of the Same Origin Policy. The domain must be the same - even down to the protocol.

Comment: @cale_b I don't get any error in my console log. In network overview (in chrome) i see that the page customers.php is loaded and status is OK

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the site making the request is using the https:// protocol.

Comment: @karthikr I put a alert in the success callback but i don't get the alert...

Comment: @LeoN its because your ajax call request failed. Add the 'error' function and check whats happening..

Comment: if i remember correctly jquery ajax doesnt like using full url's if possible try using a relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine to me,

**EDITED**
Also try removing the protocol and use `url: "//<?php echo $_conf['siteurl']; ?>/files/connect/import/customers.php",`

```
$("#TwImport").click(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://<?php echo $_conf['siteurl']; ?>/files/connect/import/customers.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert(data.percentage); 
            },
            error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                //Check for any error here
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry @RajaM, I don't really get it. What's the difference between your answer and the question code? Other than adding the error handler? Just for reference, could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @AlejandroIván please check my edited code. I just made the protocol to be auto selected..

Answer (score 0):

if you add and error callback to the ajax call you should get some error printouts to let you know what is going on

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://<?php echo $_conf['siteurl']; ?>/files/connect/import/customers.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert(data.percentage); 
            },
            error : function (e1, e2, e3) {
              console.log(e1);
              console.log(e2);
              console.log(e3);
            }


});
```

EDIT:
i just had a thought, if i remember correctly jquery ajax doesnt like using full url's if possible try using a relative path